# Why is my charger not staying plugged in?

Tags: laptop, charger

I have an MSI Gaming Laptop and today when I plugged it into the charger, the charger just slid right out. I don't know if the problem is with the charger itself or with the port on my computer. What do I do?

Comment: The _charger_ slid out? Or was it the plug? Which one? There are three on a typical laptop charger: one into the wall, one for the laptop and one in the middle, connecting the wall cable to the adapter box.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest type of charger has a plug like this, with a hole down the centre…

[image]

& a socket like this, with a pin & spring bar…

[image]

If that spring bar gets bent by the cable being yanked sideways it will no longer hold the plug, nor make proper contact to charge.
You need a new socket.

Comment: That spring bar is also a good amount of the electrical contact of the connector. If it is not holding the connector securely then there may be intermittent contact which can cause arcing or poor current flow, which may affect other electronic devices in the laptop.  The socket should be replaced by a professional, or at least someone familiar with soldering such parts.